# How to resolve must supply jdbc connections, but already given?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I am new to hibernate. I am trying basic application here are my classes and I am getting. I tried by using hibernate.properties file, then also I got same exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1435)
    at com.infiniteskills.data.Application.main(Application.java:9)
```

**here is my HibernateUtil class:**

```
package com.infiniteskills.data;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.infiniteskills.data.entities.User;

public class HibernateUtil {
  private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

  private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
      Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
      // configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
      return configuration.buildSessionFactory(
          new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
              .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
              .build());
    } catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw new RuntimeException("There was an error building the factory");
    }
  }

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
  }
}
```

**Here is my Main class**

```
package com.infiniteskills.data;

import org.hibernate.Session;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.close();
  }
}
```

**Configuration file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-configuration>
       <session-factory>

       <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

       <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
       <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ifinances</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.username">infinite</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.password">skills</property>


       <property name="show_sql">true</property>


       <mapping class="com.infiniteskills.data.entities.User"/>

    </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

**Entity class**

```
package com.infiniteskills.data.entities;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="FINANCES_USER")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="BIRTH_DATE")
    private Date birthDate;

    @Column(name="EMAIL_ADDRESS")
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name="LAST_UPDATE_DATE")
    private Date lastUpdateDate;

    @Column(name="LAST_UPDATED_BY")
    private String lastUpdatedBy;

    @Column(name="CREATED_DATE")
    private Date cteatedDate;

    @Column(name="CREATED_BY")
    private String createdBy;

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }
    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }
    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }
    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }
    public Date getLastUpdateDate() {
        return lastUpdateDate;
    }
    public void setLastUpdateDate(Date lastUpdateDate) {
        this.lastUpdateDate = lastUpdateDate;
    }
    public String getLastUpdatedBy() {
        return lastUpdatedBy;
    }
    public void setLastUpdatedBy(String lastUpdatedBy) {
        this.lastUpdatedBy = lastUpdatedBy;
    }
    public Date getCteatedDate() {
        return cteatedDate;
    }
    public void setCteatedDate(Date cteatedDate) {
        this.cteatedDate = cteatedDate;
    }
    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }
    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Looks like it doesn't detect your configuration file. Otherwise having the "hibernate.connection.url" would have ensured you never reach the UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl instantiation, which is just a dummy class. Where have you put it, and how is it named? The name is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Hibernate Util to below, this should sort out your issue of **detecting** configuration file.

```
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class HibernateUtil {
 private static SessionFactory sessionAnnotationFactory;

 public static SessionFactory getSessionAnnotationFactory() {
    if (sessionAnnotationFactory == null) {
        sessionAnnotationFactory = buildAnnotationSessionFactory();
    }
    return sessionAnnotationFactory;
 }

 private static SessionFactory buildAnnotationSessionFactory() {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    try {

        sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sessionFactory;
 }
}
```

And to fetch the SessionFactory & Session objects use the below code:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionAnnotationFactory();
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

Comment: got the same exception